# Adding transition effect to button is not working

Tags: html, css

I have added a `transition` effect to a button but it is not working. The background color is white; by adding the transition effect, the color should be moved from bottom to top but it is not effecting. Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xtn25mcd/) for that. This is the code:

```css
.hourlypricing {
  background: #57c1e8;
  border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
  min-width: 16.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-left: 265px;
  line-height: 5.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

button.monthlypricing {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
  min-width: 16.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  line-height: 5.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hourly">
  <button class="hourlypricing">Hourly Pricing</button>
  <span class="FyfR" data-reactid="5">or</span>
  <button class="monthlypricing">Monthly Pricing</button>
</div>
```

Comment: _When_ should the transition occur? You did not specify that.

Comment: maybe you want animation ?

Comment: @Xufox when the user hover on Monthly pricing it should change the background color and the color should slide from bottom to top

Comment: You don’t have any `:hover` pseudo-class selector in your CSS. How did you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `transform: scaleY()` and `transform-origin`. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.hourlypricing {
  background: #57c1e8;
  border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
  min-width: 16.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-left: 265px;
  line-height: 5.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hourlypricing:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.hourlypricing:hover:after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

button.monthlypricing {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
  min-width: 16.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  line-height: 5.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hourly">
  <button class="hourlypricing">Hourly Pricing</button>
  <span class="FyfR" data-reactid="5">or</span>
  <button class="monthlypricing">Monthly Pricing</button>
</div>
```

**Update:** For activate button you need to use scripts. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.active {
  background: #57c1e8 !important;
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

button:hover:after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

button.active:hover:after {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

button {
  background: #fff;
  border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
  min-width: 16.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  line-height: 5.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out, color .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

button.monthlypricing {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

button.hourlypricing {
  margin-left: 265px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hourly">
  <button class="hourlypricing active">Hourly Pricing</button>
  <span class="FyfR" data-reactid="5">or</span>
  <button class="monthlypricing">Monthly Pricing</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move transition definition to a separate section `.hourlypricing:hover` like this (Also I've set a transtion time to 1s for better visibility):

```css
.hourlypricing 
 {
    background: #57c1e8;
    border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
    min-width: 16.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 6rem;
 margin-left:265px;
    line-height: 5.6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none !important;}
    
.hourlypricing:hover {    
 -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out,color .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out,color 1s ease-in-out,box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: red;
    }
    
 button.monthlypricing 
 {
    margin-left: 50px;
 background:#fff;
 border: .2rem solid #57c1e8;
    min-width: 16.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 6rem;
 line-height: 5.6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
 color:#000;
    text-decoration: none !important;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out,color .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out,color .1s ease-in-out,box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hourly">                            
      <button class="hourlypricing">Hourly Pricing</button>
      <span class="FyfR" data-reactid="5">or</span>
      <button class="monthlypricing">Monthly Pricing</button>
      
      
    </div>
```

Comment: transition effect should move from bottom to top

Answer (score -1):

You not change any value

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

CSS transitions allows you to change property values smoothly from one value to another.

```css
.hourlypricing {
  background: #57c1e8;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
}

.hourlypricing:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: when adding a snippet you have to put a complete code ... or use the **code** tag instead

Comment: Not displaying any result if i click on run code snippet

Comment: @user8725518 Of course. The snippet doesn’t include the HTML, but it includes some CSS that should help you.

Comment: @Xufox then how can i check the result how it is displaying